# Want to create custom reminder

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, customization, reminders

I want to create custom reminder without using alarm, because I have requirement like when a uitextfield 's value increases than previous value the reminder need to be called.

So Is there any way for doing that ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific? Do you want am alert type of view? Also, show what you have tried/researched to implement it.

Comment: yes I want an alert type of view but using reminder(EkReminder), and I found that I can get this but using time(by setting alarm) or time interval but its none of my need.
I need a reminder when I enter like 1000 in text field and if it is greater than previous entered value in the same text field then reminder should be called.

Comment: Can I have this kind of function using local notification ??

Comment: UILocalNotification objects are useful for you if you want to notify users when your app is in background. I don't think you need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show an alert if the text entered in the textfield is greater than 1000 in length, then use
1. 
`UITextField` delegate methods. There are methods that get called at every time you enter any character in the textfield. Read [more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html). You will find a method of your needs.

2.In that method use an if-else condition to check the length of the enteterd text.
Find a property in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) which helps you getting to the length of the text entetered so far in textfield.

3.Use `UIAlertView` to show alert. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) is the link.

PS: I could have given you the code, but I think it would be more beneficial for you to read these docs and try to implement. In case you stuck somewhere, ask specific questions and we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to be more specific, but as far as I get what you need is, if the value increase then previous values. For this you need to store last entered text onto string and if user type new text then compare it and if it is increase then set or show alert view.
Add your logic into this delegate.

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Thanks. Hope it'll help.